# Django {% include %} TemplateDoesNotExist at / blog/includes/post.html

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, templates, django-templates

**Hello,good day to you,**

I'm currenttly taking a Django course where im building a blog .

i keep getting a:

**TemplateDoesNotExist at /
blog/includes/post.html**

which i can not seem to solve.

but i think it has something to do with the **{%include%}** template tag

i have two files:
**1)post.html  and 2)index.html**

**i am trying to {%include%} the post.html in the index.html**

but when i do i get this:

**TemplateDoesNotExist at /
blog/includes/post.html template does not exist error**

but i have tested the path several times
i have checked settings.py and my path is correct

```
{% include "blog/includes/post.html" %} ### HERE IS THE PROBLEM in index.html
{% include "blog/post.html" %}
{% include "blog/templates/blog/includes/post.html" %}
```

i have tried all paths none work.

the only way i can make it work is by not using the the {% include%} and instead copying and pasting the post.html directly
but this is impractical and does not let me move on with my project

this is the directory structure :

**blog / templates / blog / includes / post.html**

**blog /templates / blog /index.html**

```
##### index.html   ######

{% extends "templates/base.html" %} 
{% load static %}

{% block title %} 
My Blog 
{% endblock %} 

{% block css_files %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "blog/post.css" %}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "blog/index.css" %}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<section id="welcome">
  <header>
    <img src="{% static "blog/images/.png" %}" alt="myblog" />
    <h2>BLOG</h2>
  </header>
  <p>Hi, I love to blog about tech and the world!</p>
</section>

<section id="latest-posts">
  <h2>My Latest Thoughts</h2>

  <ul>
    {% include "blog/includes/post.html" %}### HERE IS THE PROBLEM 
  </ul>
</section>

<section id="about">
  <h2>What I Do</h2>
  <p>
     programming is fun 
  </p>
  <p>
    hello this is  my blog 
  </p>
</section>
{% endblock %}

####  post.html  ####

{% extends "templates/base.html" %} 
{% load static %}


<li>
  <article class="post">
    <a href="{% url "post-detail-page" post.slug %}">
      <img src="{% static "blog/images/"|add:post.image %}" alt="{{ post.title }}"
      />
      <div class="post__content">
        <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
        <p>
          {{ post.excerpt }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
</li>


##########TRACEBACK############

Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 3.2.11
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
['blog',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.


Template error:
In template /home/jo/My_site/templates/base.html, error at line 0
   blog/includes/post.html
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : 
   3 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   4 : <html lang="en">
   5 : <head>
   6 :   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   7 :   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   8 :   <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
   9 :   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "app.css" %}">
   10 :   {% block css_files %}{% endblock %}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 183, in render
    template = context.template.engine.select_template(template_name)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 180, in select_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(not_found))

The above exception (blog/includes/post.html) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/jo/My_site/blog/views.py", line 75, in starting_page
    <source code not available>
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 63, in render
    reraise(exc, self.backend)
  File "/home/jo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 84, in reraise
    raise new from exc

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: blog/includes/post.html


###urls.py#####

from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.starting_page, name="starting-page"),
    path("posts", views.posts, name="posts-page"),
    path("posts/<slug:slug>", views.post_detail,
         name="post-detail-page")  # /posts/my-first-post
]

###views.py####

from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def starting_page(request):
  return render(request, "blog/index.html")

def posts(request):
  return render(request, "blog/all-posts.html")

def post_detail(request):
  pass


###  settings.py  ########
Django settings for My_site project.


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "blog",
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [str.format(BASE_DIR, "/templates")
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

######
```

Comment: The problem is in your template directory do u have post.html in the directory blog/include/?

Comment: Can u share the file dir structure of templates

Comment: the file diirectories are such:   blog / templates / blog / includes / post.html

Comment: and blog /templates / blog /index.html

Comment: use {% include "includes/post.html" %} inside index.html

Comment: unfortunately this did not work :( the strange thing is , that as soon as i remove the include tag it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    ...
    'DIRS': [str.format(BASE_DIR, "/templates")]
    ...
```

to this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    ...
    'DIRS': ["templates/"]
    ...
```

and try again:

```
{% include "blog/includes/post.html" %}
```

Comment: this did not work , it continues to return the same trackeback which i have listed above, **Error during template rendering
In template /home/jo/My_site/templates/base.html, error at line 0
blog/includes/post.html**

Comment: Delete `{% extends "templates/base.html" %}` from `post.html`. You are extending twice.

Comment: I  delted as you said , i just added that extends to see if that was the problem also i get this line   :   The above exception (blog/includes/post.html) was the direct cause of the following exception:
Local vars
/home/jo/My_site/blog/views.py, line 75, in starting_page
**<source code not available> **